# Cannot display data extension value in email via AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I havent been able to make a value visible when creating an email via ContentBuilder and adding AMPscript. Here's part of the code I have:

```
<td style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:26px; color:#FFFFFF;">
%%Nombre_completo%%
</td>
```

When I go to "Preview and Test" I get the following error:

> Personalization error:`%%nombre_completo%%` To fix the problem, please
>   try the following:
>    - Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct
>   any spaces between percent signs (%%)
>    - Correct the HTML Body of your email.

Im using a Sendable Data Extension and the field "Nombre completo" is a text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nombre_completo and "Nombre completo" are two completely different attributes in the eyes of SFMC - which is why you are getting the error. I believe using %%Nombre completo%% should work with the actual space in the personalization string.  If you were to use it in AMPScript, you would need to include brackets around it. (e.g. [Nombre completo]).

What I have found to be the best way to add in personalization via attributes is by setting an AMPscript variable set via Attribute Value function. This allows for null values without throwing an error among other things.

See below:

```
%%[
var @Nombre_Completo

SET @Nombre_Completo = AttributeValue("Nombre Completo")
]%%

<td style="font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:26px; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:left;">%%=v(@Nombre_completo)=%%</td>
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting AttributeValue().  Death to raw personalization strings!

Comment: Thanks Gortonington! That worked like a charm. Would this also work for Journey Builder emails? Regards

Comment: Its Adam! thanks for jumping in... you have no idea how hard I've tried to contact you for help on a problem I have with Journey Builder and a website integration... would you please (please) give me a hand? would it be better if I created another question so you can see what Im talking about? Thanks!

Comment: This will work in all emails in SFMC.